# From where should I take the date when saving into my database?

Tags: sql, date

I have been doing a code review and I come across a code which was setting the date like this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Item_Update", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ItemId", item.Id)); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Active", false));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DeactivatedBy", item.DeactivatedBy));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DeactivatedDt", DateTime.Now)); 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This code will update an item setting the date and the person when it was deactivated (please be aware here that we set the time like this 'DateTime.Now', the time from the web server when the code is executed)

But at the same time, we have a stored procedure which updates the item and that stored procedure sets also the DeactivateDt

```
UPDATE item
SET active = 0,
    chdt = GETDATE(),
    DeactivatedBy = @ExecUserName,
    DeactivatedDt = GETDATE()
FROM    
    item
WHERE   
    id = @itemId;
```

There is nothing wrong on any of both cases, but I was wondering what is the preferred pattern when it comes to set the dates:

1. Set the date from the code
2. Set the date from SQL Server

Not sure if this is a very interesting question, but as I was not 100% sure what to respond on my code review, I have decided to ask you guys.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use SQL's `current_date`.

Comment: use can use the date function provided by `SQL` which is `getdate()` for more information have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_getdate.asp)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some non-ANSI SQL there.

Comment: There is no right answer to this question. It depends on which date or time you want to use. Do you want to use the time of the web server (or client machine), or the time of the database server? You must decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it should not matter whether you update the date from app tier or db tier. It could be business requirement also. However maintaining consistency across the application is more important from standardization & auditing point of view. This standardization would help in auditing the application in future, in case of any issues.

However, under this circumstances, given a chance, I would recommend DB layer to update the date automatically with default value as GETDATE(), when a new record is inserted.

Again to maintain consistency while updating, if your requirement is to set the same date to all, you can do something like as follows:

```
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME;

SET @currDate = GETDATE();

UPDATE table SET date = @currDate;
```

(Note: above code is untested)

Answer (score 2):

How is the data used thereafter? If it's used for any sort of *filtering*, then the most important thing is to be *consistent*.

E.g. if the code and SQL are running on different machines which have a small time difference, then you could deactivate a row and then have that same row returned by a query for active rows shortly afterwards, if you're using different clocks.

Better to pick one clock and use it everywhere - not just for this example but everywhere that time matters.

It's usually easier if that clock is the one for SQL Server.

Comment: I have thought the same as you. thank you for your answer